Infinite redirect
pom
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

config
package com.example.demo.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ParamConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/demo/{id}")
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}

controller
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/demo/{id}")
    public String getDemo(@PathVariable String id) {

        return format("get %s", id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/demo/{id}")
    public String postDemo(@PathVariable String id) {
        return format("post %s", id);
    }

}

Stacktrace
https://dpaste.org/NFSgL
Problem

There seems to be a redirect loop.
Why does this infinite redirect happen, and how can I resolve it?

anyway you are using default configuration for login, so can you update it to .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()) and also change requestMatchers config to .requestMatchers("/demo/{id}").authenticated() and try?

Most probably there is some issue with /login url, Please map that url in your controller. it might be throwing some error due to unavailable endpoint or some error in /login page.
Alternatively you can also make /error url public to check if there is any error.

I've just started studying Spring. Login page is provided by Spring Security. If I map this url myself, what logic should I put behind it? I would say it will not help me, unfortunately.

Firstly your code looks incomplete. you can try the below code ...
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/demo/*")
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

in the above code you can add the patterns like .requestMatchers("/**") if you want.
even you can try the http webignoring to ignore some api's like below:
@Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer configure() {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/demo**");
    }

do check and let me know.

Sunny, thank you for trying to help. But your code reveals a compilation error. That is anyRequest() can't be resolved in this context. I've removed this string.
And get the same error of too many redirects.

can I know your spring boot version... or you can check the code here https://github.com/s4sunnny/spring-boot-jwt-authentication

Spring boot 3.2.5.
